# How to connect a USB-C drive to an iMac with Thunderbolt ports

Tags: imac, external-disk, thunderbolt

I have iMac 27" late 2014, running 10.14.6 OS. It has 2 TB2 ports.
Wanting to connect a hard drive with USB-C only output connection.
I need to get from USB-C from the drive to my iMac via TB2.
The Apple connector says it is bi-directional but I cannot get it to work.
Is there a cable out there other than the adapter Apple supply?
I need to go TB2 so I can boot from the drive.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your external HD provide its own power? See [this Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266) under "Data Transfer" for more.

Comment: Yes it has its own power supply built in.

Comment: Upon further reading on Apple site, their adapter for this job does not cover my iMac which is late 2014. Aaaaaah.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You can't connect a USB-C external hard drive to a Thunderbolt 2 port: Thunderbolt 2 "speaks" PCI Express and DisplayPort, while the hard drive "speaks" USB. You can connect the external hard drive to your Mac with a simple USB-C-to-USB-A adapter (provided the port can supply enough power, which is normally the case for portable hard drives).

Comment: I had exactly the same question, and sadly the two Mini Displayport ports on the late 2015 iMac are Thunderbolt 2, and Thunderbolt 2 is not compatible with USB including USB-C. You'd have to have Thunderbolt 4 most likely. And the two USB ports are USB 3.0, so 5 Gbit / second or at most 625 MB/second transfer speed. Still a lot faster than an internal hard drive.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thunderbolt 2 ports are compatible with Thunderbolt 4 hubs and docks, including those with USB-C.  I experimented with this before using a Mac Mini and a Thunderbolt 4 hub I had bought for a different computer.  Using a Thunderbolt 2 cable and a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter I was able to attach the hub to the Mac Mini and get fully functional USB-C ports.  Well, "fully functional" except that the adapter didn't pass through DisplayPort video, perhaps a different adapter would preserve this capability.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you need to use a powered Dock. The dock then supplies the power to the drive. Thunderbolt 3 docks are easier to find over Thunderbolt 1 and Thunderbolt 2 docks. You can connect the Thunderbolt 3 dock to the Mac using Apple's [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter).

For example, OWC offers an [Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/docks/owc-thunderbolt-3-dock). The webpage explicitly states the dock can be used with a Thunderbolt 2 port via Apple's adaptor.

---

An alternative would be to plug a Samsung T7 (or equivalent) in to an existing USB Type A port. (A Samsung T5 is cheaper and should have about the same performance when used with your Mac.) This alternative would be slower, but does not require any additional cables, hubs or adaptors.

Comment: OK thanks for advice, my external drive already has its own power supply, would adding a powered dock into the line conflict?